# I cannot execute my script because of pywrap_tensorflow issues. ImportError: DLL load failed

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pycharm

I keep receiving this error message:
Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\keras_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in 
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\keras_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in 
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\keras_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\keras_env\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\keras_env\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Data_file_correction.py", line 5, in 
    import keras
  File "C:\keras_env\lib\site-packages\keras__init__.py", line 3, in 
    from . import utils
  File "C:\keras_env\lib\site-packages\keras\utils__init__.py", line 6, in 
    from . import conv_utils
  File "C:\keras_env\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\conv_utils.py", line 9, in 
    from .. import backend as K
  File "C:\keras_env\lib\site-packages\keras\backend__init__.py", line 89, in 
    from .tensorflow_backend import *
  File "C:\keras_env\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 5, in 
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\keras_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow__init__.py", line 24, in 
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\keras_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python__init__.py", line 49, in 
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\keras_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in 
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\keras_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in 
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\keras_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in 
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\keras_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\keras_env\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\keras_env\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

import keras
import tensorflow

Comment: Is `keras_env` a conda environment? Which PyCharm version do you use?